# DoctrineExtensions Uploadable on entity update doesn't keep current value

Tags: symfony, doctrine, stofdoctrineextensions, doctrine-uploadable

I am using Uploadable extension and very happy with that. 
I have entity with one field as an Uploadable (photo), and another field is annotation for that photo (annotation). When I first create entity I choose the file, and put annotation and everything works okay, but when I want to update just annotation it loses the stored path of the previously uploaded photo. Is there a way to keep old values if null coming for that field?

This is my entity.

```
/**
 * Photo
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Uploadable(
 *     path="up/photo",
 *     allowOverwrite=false,
 *     appendNumber=true,
 *     allowedTypes="image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,image/x-png"
 * )
 */
class Photo
{
      /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="annotation", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $annotation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\UploadableFilePath
     * @Assert\File(
     *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/x-png"}
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $photo;
```

And this is my Controller part:

```
        if ($entity->getPhoto()) {
            $uploadableManager = $this->get('stof_doctrine_extensions.uploadable.manager');
            $uploadableManager->markEntityToUpload($entity, $entity->getPhoto());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change setter on your entity:

```
public function setPhoto($photo) {
    if (!$photo) {return $this;}
    $this->photo = $photo;
    return $this;
```

Comment: I think you mean setter for photo, not for annotation. When I try that it throws an error: You must pass an instance of FileInfoInterface or a valid array for entity of class "AdminBundle\Entity\Photo".

Comment: Yes you're right, I made mistake, check my edit, should works, if no you can change `!photo` to `$photo = ''`, you can do the same with annotation when you upload new photo and want to keep annotation.

Comment: You will still get the exception with error message: "You must pass an instance of FileInfoInterface or a valid array for entity of class "AdminBundle\Entity\Photo""